# Can you add passengers to an existing Tallink Silja booking?

Tags: bookings, cruising, tallink-silja

If I've made a booking for one person with a cabin for four, is it then possible to add 3 more people to that booking afterwards? How do I do that if it's possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be changed on all routes excluding the Tallinn - Helsinki route according to the [Terms and Conditions](https://www.tallinksilja.com/travel-terms-and-conditions-for-individuals):

> 4) The passenger cannot change the direction and/or itinerary, the date and time of departure or the number of passengers less than 24 hours before departure.

Whereas for the Tallin - Helinski route:

> 4) The passenger cannot change the direction and/or itinerary, the date and time of departure or the number of passengers less than 45 minutes before departure.

I assume you will find the option to add passengers online or else you might need to [contact them](https://www.tallinksilja.com/travel-terms-and-conditions-for-individuals):

> Email: **international.sales@tallinksilja.com**
>
> Phone number: **+49(0)40 547 541 222**

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder edited answer

Comment: Welcome back Daniil!

Comment: In practise you can always add more passengers (if there are available beds in your cabin) until the minute the gate closes. You simple go to a manned kiosk to do it. I've done it maybe 100 times with Tallink Silja.